# Can I add one XmlDocument within a node of another XmlDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have two XmlDocuments. Something like:

```
<document1>
  <inner />
</document1>
```

and

```
<document2>
  <stuff/>
</document2>
```

I want to put document2 inside of the inner node of document1 so that I end up with a single docement containing:

```
<document1>
  <inner>
    <document2>
      <stuff/>
    </document2>
  </inner>
</document1>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the code...

```
XmlDocument document1, document2;
// Load the documents...
XmlElement xmlInner = (XmlElement)document1.SelectSingleNode("/document1/inner");
xmlInner.AppendChild(document1.ImportNode(document2.DocumentElement, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, but effectively a copy will be created. You have to use `XmlNode node = document1.ImportNode(document2.RootElement)`, find the node  and add `node` as a child element.

Example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can only have on XmlDocument in an XML DOM.  What you want to do is get the DocumentElement associated with document2 and append that XmlElement as a child to the  XmlElement.